# How to bind a TextBox to a Class

Tags: c#, uwp, binding, textbox

How would I go about binding the text in a `TextBox` on one page to a global class from another?

My current code:

**App.xaml.cs**

```
public static CustomerClass customer = new CustomerClass();
```

**AddCustomer.xaml**

```
<TextBox x:Name="txtLastName" PlaceholderText="Last name" 
         Text="{x:Bind Path=local:App.customer.LastName}"/>
```

`{x:Bind Path=local:App.customer.LastName}` isn't throwing any errors however when I type into the `TextBox` the value in the class remains null and doesn't update.

1. Have I bound the values correctly?
2. If so how do I get the class to update?

**Edit:**

1. Yes I had bound it correctly
2. All I had to do was add the properties `Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`

**Solution:**

```
{x:Bind Path=local:App.customer.LastName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}
```

Comment: [Data binding in depth, including {x:Bind} markup extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth)

Comment: It seems you have found the solution.You can post the answer directly if you solve your issue.That would be helpful for other communities who meet the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes it is bound correctly
2. All you have to do is use the properties `Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`

**Solution:**

```
{x:Bind Path=local:App.customer.LastName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}
```